# Couch DB relationship modelling - searching & sorting

Tags: reactjs, couchdb, relationship, pouchdb

I am building a site using Couchdb and ReactJS.

One of my pages displays a list of up to 10,000 financial transactions, each txn consisting of:

- date
- in amount
- out amount
- payee
- category item
- notes

I have a pagination strategy and only load and display 100 transactions at a time.

At any one time, I want to be able to search a single column - I use a drop down to tell the search functionality which index to use for searching.

I also want to be able to sort each column.

So far I have used multiple views and I have all of the above functionality working.

During development I used a string for the category item. Now that I have worked out how to get all of the above to work, I need to properly tackle the category item column entry.

A category item belongs to a category, so a category can have one or more category items so there is a one to many relationship between the category and the items.

Each txn can have one and only one category item.

A category is made up of a small number of fields.

A category item is made up of a small number of fields.

I am struggling to find the best approach to doing this.

I have considered each of the approaches described in https://docs.couchbase.com/server/5.0/data-modeling/modeling-relationships.html.

At this point, I am considering one of the following approaches and I was wondering if anyone had any advice - I have include examples of the txns, cats and cat items at the end of this post?

1. Embed the cat item in the txn and hopefully suss how to both search and sort on the cat item.name
2. Abandon pagination and load all the txns into the virtual dom, and sort and search the dom directly

Currently each distinct item is a separate document and I use referencing to maintain the relationship. I have considered using the id to store searching and sorting data but I don't see how this would work to give me all that I need.

**Txn**

```
{
    "_id": "1",
    "type": "txn"
    "date": "2020-01-20",
    "cat": "3",
    "notes": "xxxx",
    "out": 10,
    "in": 0
}
```

**Category**

```
{
    "_id": "2",
    "type": "cat",
    "name": "Everyday Expenses",
    "weight": 2
}
```

**Category Item**

```
{
    "_id": "3",
    "type": "catitem",
    "cat": "2",
    "name": "Groceries (£850)",
    "weight": 0,
    "notes": "blah, blah, blah"
}
```

I am running ReactJS on node.js and I am using pouchdb.